# BigQuery subtract elements in array

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I was wondering how I could calculate the difference between elements in arrays that have only two elements, by subtracting the lesser from the greater.

I started by referring to the code sample from the BQ documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#arrays_and_aggregation) with a few tweaks of my own to leave only 2 elements in the arrays. I know this example is for SUMs, but I was wondering if there's a way to modify it to calculate differences.

```
WITH sequences AS
  (SELECT [0, 5] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT [2, 32] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT [5, 10] AS some_numbers)
SELECT some_numbers,
  (SELECT SUM(x)
   FROM UNNEST(s.some_numbers) x) AS sums
FROM sequences s;
```

These are my desired results.

```
+--------------------+------+
| some_numbers       | diff |
+--------------------+------+
| [0, 5]             | 5    |
| [2, 32]            | 30   |
| [5, 15]            | 10   |
+--------------------+------+
```

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant my apologies. I am aware of the rules. I was going to read through all answers before selecting one, but I had a lot of work to do and ended up forgetting to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH sequences AS (
  SELECT [0, 5] AS some_numbers UNION ALL 
  SELECT [2, 32] AS some_numbers UNION ALL 
  SELECT [5, 10] AS some_numbers
)
SELECT some_numbers, 
  ABS(some_numbers[OFFSET(0)] - some_numbers[OFFSET(1)]) diff
FROM sequences
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the answers already posted to further contribute with the comunity, I would suggest the use of ***User Defined Functions (UDF)*** in BigQuery.

This resource allows you to create functions in *SQL* or *JavaScript*, which accept columns of input and execute actions, returning the desired result after the transformations. I would also add that they are easy to modify in case it is needed (from a sum to a subtraction function, for instance). You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-javascript-libraries).

I created a UDF using JavaScript, it is below:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  sub_arr (arr ARRAY<int64>)
  RETURNS int64
  LANGUAGE js AS '''
arr_sub=0
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr_sub = parseInt(arr[i]) - arr_sub ;
  };
  return arr_sub;
''';

#Sample data
WITH
  data AS (
  SELECT [2, 7] AS some_array UNION ALL
  SELECT [10, 32] AS some_array UNION ALL
  SELECT [15,20] AS some_array )

#query using the UDF
SELECT sub_arr(some_array) AS result_diff
FROM data
```

and the output,

[image]

I would like to point that you have to specify the type of array you will use in the function, in this case `ARRAY<int64>`. Furthermore, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#supported-javascript-udf-data-types) *Javascript's UDF* does not accept `INT64` as a return type and it converts to `FLOAT64`, it is a good practice to pay attention in the data types you are using.

Answer (score 1):

How about just subtracting?

```
WITH sequences AS (
   SELECT [0, 5] AS some_numbers union all
   SELECT [2, 32] AS some_numbers union all
   SELECT [5, 10] AS some_numbers
   )
select some_numbers,
       some_numbers[ordinal(2)] - some_numbers[ordinal(1)]
from sequences;
```